# Thresholding a numpy array with different threshold on each column

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do exactly what this question asked for R in Python: [Different hard threshold for each column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50881398/1336939) That is, apply a different threshold per column on an $n\times m$ numpy array.

The only way I know is to iterate over the columns but there must be a vectorial way to do it (perhaps using views or strides)?

Comment: numpy is a bit different from R. you can use https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html , ```A[A>thresh] = .. ``` will work. One of answers seem to be going in this direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `broadcasting`:

```
a = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)
thresh = np.array([3, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15])

a > thresh[None,:]
```

Output:

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: You don't need the extra dimension. Broadcasting lines up the last dimension. `a > thresh` is sufficient.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it concisely exemplifies broadcasting (and it was the first one to do so), which seems to be the simplest way to do it. From the other answers that use broadcasting, I would have accepted @anon01's because it answers what the original R question was asking.

Comment: is there an efficient way to use the boolean mask to threshold without creating a threshold matrix the same size as `a`?  Was hoping for `a[a < thresh] = thresh`, but this does not work

Comment: @anon01 `np.minimum(a, thresh)`?

Comment: ah cool!   What about if you want different threshold/fill values by column?

Answer (score 1):

Here

- `m` is the original matrix
- `thresh_vals` is a list (np array) of threshold values
- `rep_vals` is a list of corresponding values to fill for m < thresh_vals

Threshold and replace values via the following:

```
m = np.random.rand(4,4)

thresh_vals = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0])
m_thresh = np.repeat(thresh_vals.reshape(1,4), 4, axis=0)

rep_vals = np.array([0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001])
m_rep = np.repeat(rep_vals.reshape(1,4), 4, axis=0)

mask = m < thresh_vals
m[mask] = m_rep[mask]


# m:
[[0.85129154 0.76109774 0.20486053 0.07527921]
 [0.97887779 0.70202094 0.11273641 0.98444799]
 [0.50364255 0.05257619 0.58271136 0.41479196]
 [0.39269314 0.01727273 0.81580523 0.93713313]] 

# m after threshold applied, filled with `rep_vals`:
[[0.85129154 0.76109774 0.01       0.001     ]
 [0.97887779 0.70202094 0.01       0.001     ]
 [0.50364255 0.1        0.01       0.001     ]
 [0.39269314 0.1        0.81580523 0.001     ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your matrix to the threshold array directly

if x is a [n,m] numpy array and t is a [m,] numpy array

```
x > t
```

returns a boolean [n,m] array, checking whether each column in x is greater than the respective threshold in t

Example:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([
[0,1,2],
[1,2,3],
[2,3,4]])

t = np.array([1,2,3])

v >= t

>> array([[False, False, False],
   [ True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True]])
```